# Need help converting cURL command to Javascipt

Tags: javascript, curl, axios

I am trying to get recipe nutritional information from Edamam API.  In the API docs, the cURL command is:

```
curl -d @recipe.json -H "Content-Type: application/json" "https://api.edamam.com/api/nutrition-details?app_id=${YOUR_APP_ID}&app_key=${YOUR_APP_KEY}"
```

I am using Axios and Javascript to try to access the API with a Post command:

```
import axios from "axios";

var postData = './recipe.json'

let axiosConfig = {
  headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',}
};

axios.post('https://api.edamam.com/api/nutrition-details?app_id=XXXXXXXX&app_key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX', postData, axiosConfig)
.then((res) => {
  console.log("RESPONSE RECEIVED: ", res);
})
.catch((err) => {
  console.log("AXIOS ERROR: ", err);
})
```

I receive a 400 error back.  Any thoughts on what I need to do to make this work would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with cURL, but I think the command is a GET and you're trying to send a POST request in the JS.

Answer (score 2):

`postData` needs to be a string of JSON.

You appear to be passing it a string containing a filename.

You might want to read `'./recipe.json'` with `axios.get()` to fetch the data from it.

Comment: `postData` could also be a standard JS object, so you can also import the JSON using `import postDate from './recipe.json'`.

Answer (score 0):

In your **cURL** the option `-d @recipe.json` is sending the content of the file **recipe.json**

But, In your **Code** `postData = './recipe.json'`, You are just passing the name instead of reading it.

First you need to read the data from **recipe.json**,Then you need to send it through request.